# .NET Core 3 - Angular Template - Angular Assets not deploying in Azure via DevOps

Tags: angular, azure, azure-devops, single-page-application, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm attempting to deploy a project to an Azure AppService using Azure DevOps.

I created the project via the .NET Core 3 angular template using `dotnet new angular -o projectname`.

When deploying to azure, I'm able to hit the APIs, but i get a 404 on the root. The webpage isn't loading.

I went into the Azure AppService editor to look at the deployed files.  While the angular app is being built and published in the pipeline (and those assets make it into the zip file), those files are NOT being deployed to the app service in the release.

[image: Files are in the zip, but not in the appservice?]

I attempted to use unzip in the kudu console to force the files in, but i get this error:
[image: can't unzip]

Any insight into this / suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: I also noticed it didn't drop in the automapper dlls?? -- that zip is the "a.zip" highlighted in the AppServiceEditor.

Comment: Hi Did you have a try using the Extract files task in your pipeline as below answer mentioned? How did it go?

Answer (score 0):

If you deployed your project to an Azure AppService using Azure DevOps. You can try adding a [Extract files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/extract-files?view=azure-devops) to unzip the a.zip file in your pipeline before deploying to Azure.

For below example, configure the `Archive file patterns` and the `Destination folder` according to your project.

[image]

You can aslo add a [Delete files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/delete-files?view=azure-devops) to remove the a.zip file from your artifacts after it has been unzipped in Extract files task .

Hope above helps!

Comment: So, the a.zip file contains everything, and is the artifact from the build pipeline.  It conatins the anuglar code AND the .net core code.  And it seems that somehow the deployment task is selectively extracting only the .net core stuff?